# How to access parent class from child's Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I have added one Xcode project (C) as child to parent Xcode project (P). How to access parent's class from child's project?

when i try to import P's class from C's class, getting the error as "file not found"

[image: Error]

[image: Project structure]

Comment: show your code here

Comment: I update the question with screen shots with links

Comment: So you want to import AddressBookFramework's class in your class?

Comment: Yes. In fact i want to import some more classes of parent project from child project.

Comment: is the class included in the target membership?

Comment: No. Can you more specific